# Oracle APEX & JavaScript - Passing name of textfield in function NOT value

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a function that will need the Name of a textfield, like `P12_ACCOUNT_ID` But when I call a function on that page with: `callMyFunction('P12_ACCOUNT_ID');` it will pass the value of this textfield on to the function.

Is there a way to create a link to URL which will be javascript, and make `P12_ACCOUNT_ID` a varchar?

Just to be clear: I want my function to work with the varchar: 'P12_ACCOUNT_ID' and not with the value of that textfield.

This is the function to be called in which I want my page item to be loaded.
The link to this function now is: `javascript:callMyPopup('P12_ACCOUNT_ID')` but when it retrieves the content of this textfield and doesn't pass the string on by itself.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  function callMyPopup (paramItem) {
    var hiddenField = document.getElementById(paramItem).value;
    var url;
  url = 'f?p=&APP_ID.:3:&APP_SESSION.::::P3_HIDDEN:' + hiddenField;
  w = open(url,"winLov","Scrollbars=1,resizable=1,width=800,height=600");
  if (w.opener == null)
  w.opener = self;
  w.focus();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: can you post your codes for that function?

Comment: What's the relevant event? Because you would probably just get if from the ID from 'this' object

Comment: In Apex you can get the value of an item using `$v(paramItem)`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. Submit it as an answer so I can close this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As provided by Jeffrey Kemp but he didn't post an answer and I do want to close this question:
In Apex you can get the value of an item using `$v(paramItem)`.